# MySQL база данных для хранения данных WordPress сайтов

Tags: mysql, wordpress, база-данных, elementor

Есть страница

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я узнал данные страницы хранятся в базе данных. В какой базе данных и как отредактировать базу?

Answer (score 0):

Активную базу можно найти в настройках в файле wp-config.php

```
/** Имя базы данных для WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'XXXXXXXXX');

/** Имя пользователя MySQL */
define('DB_USER', 'XXXXXXXXX');

/** Пароль к базе данных MySQL */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXXXXXX');

/** Имя сервера MySQL */
define('DB_HOST', 'XXXXXXXXX');
```

Данные страницы хранятся в двух таблица #__posts, #__postmeta

ID страницы можно узнать при редактирование в wp-admin. Например, адрес изменения страницы /wp-admin/post.php?post=45&action=edit - соответственно ID = 45

Найти в базе таблицу #__posts и запись с ID = 45. Отредактировать поле #__posts.post_content

Comment: Элементор всё хранит в нескольких postmeta, в сериализованном виде